# lex yacc compare two strings

Tags: c, string, equals, yacc, lex

I'm really new in lex and yacc, I'd like to write an extremely simply program that asks input for a string, stores it in a variable, and checks if the same value is inserted once again. Lets say:

```
input1 = 'abc'
input2 = 'def'
input3 = 'ghi'
input4 = 'def'
STOP input2 equals input4
```

part of my **lex** file:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
%}
alpha [a-zA-Z]
%%
{alpha}* return ID;
```

part of my **yacc** file

```
%{
# include <stdio.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <string.h>
%}

%union {
       char* lexeme;            
       }

%token ID 
%%
```

all the inputs should be matched within the ID token.

Comment: You need to keep a table of your variables and their content. This isn't really something that Yacc will do for you, but something you'll have to write normal C (or other language) code to do. Yacc will just help you to check the format of the input, and call your code when a new assignment has been found in the input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex/Lex - How do I know if a variable was declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284546/flex-lex-how-do-i-know-if-a-variable-was-declared)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the `return ID;` 
I would have returned `*yytext` which contains your token in a `char*`.
You can actually take a look at this simple [calculator example](http://www.epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/index.html)

About your issue, you may need to create/implement a list of `char*` to store each of your input token during the parsing, and then check if the current one belongs to the list. As this requires more work, the examples above (and on all the website) should help.

Comment: the previously inserted snippet works fine, it returns what expected. I'm looking for some suggestion about how to convert ID into a variable, read many of them and prompting user in case of duplicate entry.